# the right way to pass variable to a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, anonymous-function

When I have

```
$('#div').click(function(someVar){//do something with soneVar});
```

but I want to have a named callback function, am I palcing the passed `someVar` correctly?

```
$('#div').click(someFunction(someVar));
function someFunction(someVar){}
```

Answer (score 9):

Both of your examples are wrong.

Your first example creates a *parameter* to the callback method named `someVar`; it will become the `event` object that jQuery passes to the handler method.

The second example calls the method immediately, then passes its *result* to the `click` method as an event handler.

You you need to pass a function expression that calls your function with a parameter from the outer scope (using a closure):

```
$('#div').click(function() { someFunction(someVar); });
```

Answer (score 7):

The `click` callback function will be passed a jQuery Event object, not `someVar`.

You have to call your function yourself *within* the callback function.

```
$('#div').click(function(ev) {
    someFunction(someVar);
}

function someFunction(someVar) {
     ...
}
```

Alternatively, do:

```
$('#div').click({someVar: someVar}, someFunction);

function someFunction(ev) {
    // your var is now in ev.data.someVar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into passing the arguments as event data to the click event (or any event with jQuery): http://api.jquery.com/click/